# Power Automate Desktop '[Errno 2] No such file or directory when running powershell script

Tags: python, powershell, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to use power automate desktop to run a python script. Since power automate desktop does not have an action to run a python3 script (only python 2), I have to use the run powershell script action instead. I am passing the path to my python interpreter and the absolute path to my python script. However, when I run the flow, I get:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\myname\Source\Repos\Projects\Solution\HQ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It is cutting off the rest of my path because there is white space, which I wasn't aware was an issue when creating the repository that my scripts are in. Is there a way around running the powershell script to acknowledge the rest of the path without having to rename anything?

Comment: \" C:\Users...\file.py \"    like this?

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't help when executing it inside power automate desktop i guess

Comment: I figured it would be a hard question to find the answer to, but yes I tried the single quotes. For reference I used this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGKCuSrqsas    Essentially, I am just putting the path to my python interpreter and then the path to my .py file and that's it. The only issue it gives me is with my path

Comment: gives me an unexpected token error

Comment: It must be a _separate statement_, so you must either place it on a separate line or terminate it with `;`. I see that _unescaped_ `"..."` worked, after all, based on what answer you accepted - glad to hear it, but note that it contradicts your claim that `'...'` _didn't_ work (which would only be true if the path itself contained `'` chars.).

Comment: The _tl;dr_ is: the use of PowerShell Automate Desktop appears to be  _incidental_ to your question: using regular PowerShell syntax is seemingly all that is needed. If you had included the actual command you used in your question, this would likely have been obvious.

Comment: I had stored the paths in variables. i put it like this: %pathtopython% %pathtoscript% and ran it. No matter what I did to those variables I got an error. Once took the values out and changed it to the answer I accepted, it worked for some reason. Couldn't tell you why

Comment: Understood. In this case it would be interesting to know whether `& "%pathtopython%" "%pathtoscript%"` works (possibly, making the `"` part of the variable values may work too, but the former is conceptually preferable). If that works, so should`& '%pathtopython%' '%pathtoscript%'`, as long as neither variable value contains `'` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calling your Python script via PowerShell, make sure both the path to the Python interpreter and the script path are enclosed in quotes. Your command should look something like this:

```
& "C:\Path\To\Python3\python.exe" "C:\Users\myname\Source\Repos\Projects\Solution\HQ My Script.py"
```